# CKEditor: Disable default linking of email ids

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor recent version. Whenever a user types his email ID an anchor link is created.  Like `<a href="mailto:abcd@example.com">abcd@example.com</a>` is created in the output. How do I disable this property in CKEditor configuration.

I tried `config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;` and it didnt help in this particular case.

Comment: Yes. This is mostly IE issue.

Answer (score 1):

Auto Url Detection is an IE feature, and as of IE9 you can disable this.

> Prior to IE9, it was not possible to specify IDM_AUTOURLDETECT_MODE from JavaScript, meaning that pages could not disable automatic hyperlinking in ContentEditable areas. A new command constant AutoUrlDetect is supported in IE9, allowing script to disable automatic hyperlinking as follows:  document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false)

You could try executing this call on the editor's document object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also, before CKeditor creates the output (for example the moment the user clicks on the submit button) search for @ in input and replace them with `&#64;`